# Operators in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python version 2.73
Here is my code

```
x=int(raw_input('Enter first number\n'))
y=int(raw_input('Enter second number\n'))
z=x%y
print('%d % %d = %d' %(x,y,z))
```

Now the print statement is throwing me an error.
I want my output to look like

```
Enter first number
3
Enter second number
2
3 % 2 = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to double the lone percent sign otherwise python tries to interpret the next character as a formatting character:

```
'%d %% %d = %d' %(a,b,c)
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend `format` since the `%` formatting is bound to be deprecated (and as a bonus you don't have to "escape" the percent sign in your case:

```
'{} % {} = {}'.format(a,b,c)
```

(and your variables are called `x,y,z` well that is easy to figure out)

Comment: Thanks! But can you just explain me why we need to user double %

Comment: see my edit. `%` is used to delimit format. Sole `%` followed by space triggers an error because space is not a valid formatting character.

Answer (score 3):

Your variables are called `x`, `y` and `z`, not `a`, `b` and `c`. Additionally, you need to escape the `%` literal by doubling it.

```
print('%d %% %d = %d' % (x, y, z))
# Here ----^
# Here ------------------^
```